# Show two data labels in plotting column?

Tags: highcharts

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/vecmftmh/

This is the data label portion of the example:

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    allowOverlap: true
                }
            }
        }
```

This plot shows a data label on top of each column. How could I also show a data label inside each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any option on **Highcharts** to handle two datalabels. But you can use this workaround with **`dataLabels.formatter`** and **`useHTML:true`**:

```
useHTML:true,
formatter: function() {
    return '<div class="datalabel" style="position: relative; top: 20px"><b>'+ this.y +
           '</div><br/><div class="datalabelInside" style="position: absolute; top: 45px"><b>'+ this.y +'</div>';
}
```

This way you can manually add two **`dataLabels`** with custom position and style. In your case, one inside columns and one outside. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vecmftmh/1/).

Answer (score 3):

See this: `Since v6.2.0, multiple data labels can be applied to each single point by defining them as an array of configs.`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-multiple